# How to add an event to only 1 page in jquery mobile

Tags: events, jquery-mobile

When I add an event to a certain page the problem in jquery mobile is that the page stays intact when navigating to other pages (via ajax). Is there a good way to add a certain event only to certain pages (like it would be if you would leave the page).

Right now all i can do is listen to the 'pagechange' and remove the event, but then again i need to re-enable it when i go back. Is there not a better way?

Comment: could you please clarify your question? Add unique ID to page and attach event to it.

Comment: I want to add a handler on the scroll event. But is event is on the window/document which remains between pagechanges.

Comment: give that page an ID and `$(window).on("scroll", function () { var active = $.mobile.activePage[0].id; if (active = "pageID") { code } });` if you're using jQM 1.4 `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;`

Comment: Yes im doing something like that. But the evenhandler is still here. They can pileup if you navigate through a lot of pages. I hoped there would be a better solution

Comment: are you using _multi-page_ or _single page_ model?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kh63v/ if you're using _multi-page_ model

Comment: Multi page. That is why its stacking up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45645/discussion-between-omar-and-michiel-thalen)